# How to disable command block logging into the log files in minecraft

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Hi, I have a single player world which is opened to LAN to let my friends play while I am AFK. I have a lot of command blocks running in that world and those commands are all logged in the log files.

So, my question is, how to only log player commands and chat?

Correct me if I am wrong, thank you.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There are 2 `/gamerule`s that govern Command Block Output to the chat. The one you are looking for is

`/gamerule logAdminCommands false`

The the [wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Command_Block#Output) entry on command blocks for more information.

> ###Output Message###
>
> The output message describes the success or failure of the executed command, and may be written to multiple destinations:
> [...]

> **Chat:** The output message is written to the chat text in singleplayer mode, or broadcast to all other ops in multiplayer mode, unless it has been suppressed with

> `/gamerule commandBlockOutput false`.

> Some commands may write additional text to the chat as their normal function which won't be suppressed (for example, the `/say` command will write a message to the chat of all players), separate from the output message. [...]

> **Logs:** The output message is written to multiplayer server logs unless it has been suppressed with

> `/gamerule logAdminCommands false`.

Comment: Is there a way to do this on an actual server (vanilla)?

Comment: @RetroCraft, a little late but this is vanilla.

Comment: i know it's been a while, but this is the closest thing i've seen to what i'm looking for:  can you also supress the chat output of messages like /give and /tp.  sometimes a user has a legitimate gripe over a loss or whatever and i don't need the rest of the server piling on having seen me restoring an item or moving another to a safe place.

Comment: @WhiteRau I believe only OPs can even *see* these messages, but I'm not sure. I also remember seeing this posted as a question recently, but I can't find it at the moment. I suggest you search the site yourself, and if you don't find anything, please ask it as a new question, so that everyone can benefit from it in the future.

Answer (score 3):

So the problem is the capitalization of the line.

It is not like this:

```
/gamerule commandBlockoutput false
```

It is like this:

```
/gamerule commandBlockOutput false
```

It should work.

And if you're doing it from the vanilla server console, remove the forward slash.

```
gamerule commandBlockOutput false
```

Comment: This was downvoted but it was exactly what I was looking for. Any reason why it shouldn't be upvoted?